# Distributing Apps Outside the Mac App Store crash with Code Signature Invalid error

Tags: macos, release, code-signing

I have a Mac App for OS X 10.10 that I am trying to create a working release build.

- Not for the Mac App store "Distributing Apps Outside the Mac App
  Store"
- Uses "Developer ID Application" for the release code signing. Things look good in my App dev account
- Created an OSX APP ID com.blah.app
- Can create and verify an Archive successfully
- sudo spctl --assess --verbose=4 Name.App, looks good "Name.App : accepted
  source=Developer ID"
- Read thru Apple "Distributing Apps Outside the Mac App Store"
- Needs to be OS X 10.10 due to customer requirements
- Read through everything I can find on stack overflow regarding this
  matter
- Can build and release iOS without a second thought, but this is my
  first Mac App

I run the App and in the console I see "EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)"

Stumped ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the selected capabilities (red) that wasn't stopping the build, "Key chain sharing" in this case. Turned off as I didn't need it and everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

**Gatekeeper**

Macs have a "gatekeeper" feature that can be set in 3 modes in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > "Allow apps downloaded from:".

Which is your test system set to ?

Since you're signing using a Developer ID, it needs to be set to the 2nd or 3rd option (not just allowing the App store).  [2nd option is the default on freshly installed machines]

**Build for distribution outside of the app store**

Builds that you create for submission to the App store cannot be run by everybody. One needs to build it specifically for that.

To quote https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1884/_index.html :

> [...] use Xcode Organizer > Export > Export a Developer ID-signed Application. Developer ID-signed apps can be run by anyone. However, code that uses technologies only available to Mac App Store apps, such as receipt validation, iCloud, and push notifications, will not work if your app is Developer ID-signed. You might need to temporarily disable those parts of your app if you opt for the Developer ID testing approach

Comment: Mac App Store and identified developers. I would expect the warning dialog is any case? I set it to anywhere and still get the problem.

Comment: did you have a look at this ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1884/_index.html

Comment: I did. The App isn't for the Mac App Store alas, it's a simple Midi utility App. It's finished so I'm working on the distribution side of things aka the "Release" build.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks indirectly. Reading thru that article and I had a got it moment. There was an error in the selected capabilities that wasn't stopping the build, "Key chain sharing" in this case. Turned off as I didn't need it and everything works as expected.